# Override CSS class in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, css, hover, stylesheet

I have CSS like this:

```
LinkButton:hover
{
    color:White;
    background-color:Gray;
}
.myClass
{
    color:Blue;
}
```

My problem is I have a linkbutton with `CssClass .myClass` and whenever I hovers over it, it's background colour changes but color is not turning to white, is there any way to override `.myClass` by `LinkButton:hover` ?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your selector. I works with here http://jsfiddle.net/v4gsY/ with .myClass:hover selector.

Comment: It also worked on my environment.. thanks...
it will be better if it posted as answer

Comment: @RohitChaudhari asp.net controls also treated as html controls so link button is treated as anchor tag so put a instead of linkbutton

Comment: @RSquare I already have the same hover for anchor but it doesn't affected any

Comment: @RohitChaudhari simply define class and put hover for that class and use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
http://jsfiddle.net/v4gsY/
```

CSS

```
.myClass:hover
{
    color:White;
    background-color:Gray;
}
```

The LinkButton CSS selector will not work as it is converted to a  tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
 a:hover
{
  color:White;
  background-color:Gray;
}
.myClass
{
 color:Blue;
}
```

the linkbutton will render like anchor tag in the html page, so we need to write styles for a tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
LinkButton:hover
{
    color:White !important;
    background-color:Gray;
}
```

or

```
a:hover
{
    color:White !important;
    background-color:Gray;
}
```